# javascript is not working with asp.net content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have java script code to set some of the properties of ajax controls.

the code is working OK If I put it in asp.net page but when I use content page and post the code in part of the code will not work which is changing the value of ajax control properties.

My page has textbox, checkbox, MaskedEditExtender and MaskedEditValidator.
when the user check the box the mask property and some other properties should change.

the code is working ok but not the content page.

here is my code from asp.net page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>


    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>  
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">  
        <title></title>  
   </head>  
    <body>  
       <form id="form1" runat="server">  
       <div>  
           <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />  
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
               <ContentTemplate>  
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4" Width="200" />  
                   <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender6" runat="server" Mask="999"  
                       DisplayMoney="None" MaskType="number" TargetControlID="TextBox4" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"  
                       InputDirection="RightToLeft" AutoComplete="False">  
                   </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>  
                   <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator6" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender6"  
                       ControlToValidate="TextBox4" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid data" IsValidEmpty="True"  
                       TooltipMessage="Numbers Only">  
                   </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>  
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="CheckChange(this)" AutoPostBack="false" />  
  </ContentTemplate>  
           </asp:UpdatePanel>  

  <script type="text/javascript">  
  function CheckChange(sender) {  
  if (sender.checked == true) {  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_Mask("??????");  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6")._convertMask();  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_MaskType(AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.None);  
  MaskedEditValidator6.TooltipMessage = "Any character!"  
  } else {  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_Mask("999");  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6")._convertMask();  
  $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_MaskType(AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.Number);  
  MaskedEditValidator6.TooltipMessage = "Numbers Only";  
  }  
  }  

  </script>  
  </div>  
  </form>  
  </body>  
  .</html>
```

.......................................................
Here is my code from the content page
......................................................

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
function CheckChange(sender) {
    if (sender.checked == true) {
        alert("yes");
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_Mask("??????");
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6")._convertMask();
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_MaskType(AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.None);
        MaskedEditValidator6.TooltipMessage = "Any character!"
    } else {
    alert("no");
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_Mask("999");
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6")._convertMask();
        $find("MaskedEditExtender6").set_MaskType(AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditType.Number);
        MaskedEditValidator6.TooltipMessage = "Numbers Only";
    }
}  
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
               <ContentTemplate>  
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4" Width="200" /> 

                   <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender6" runat="server" Mask="999"  
                       DisplayMoney="None" MaskType="number" TargetControlID="TextBox4" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"  
                       InputDirection="RightToLeft" AutoComplete="False">  
                   </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>  
                   <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator6" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender6"  
                       ControlToValidate="TextBox4" InvalidValueMessage="Invalid data" IsValidEmpty="True"  
                       TooltipMessage="Numbers Only">  
                   </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>  
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="CheckChange(this)" AutoPostBack="false" />  
  </ContentTemplate>  
           </asp:UpdatePanel>  

</asp:Content>
```

...................................
here is my masterpage code
.....................................

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>I.M.A.M</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <style type="text/css">
        .style17
        {
            height: 43px;
        }
        .style18
        {
            width: 577px;
            height: 43px;
        }
        .style19
        {
            height: 387px;
        }
        .style20
        {
            width: 577px;
            height: 387px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>

        <table class="style1" frame="vSides">
            <tr>
                <td class="style17" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                </td>
                <td class="style18" style="">
                    <img alt="" src="Images/banner1.gif" 
                        style="width: 950px; height: 89px; margin-bottom: 0px;" /></td>
                <td class="style17" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style15">
                </td>
                <td class="style16" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Width="44px" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" BackColor="#FFFBD6" 
                        DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                        ForeColor="#990000" StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                        <StaticMenuStyle BorderStyle="Dotted" />
                        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" />
                        <DynamicItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Text") %>
                        </DynamicItemTemplate>
                        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" />
                        <StaticItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Text") %>
                        </StaticItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Menu>

                </td>
                <td class="style15">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                </td>
                <td class="style20">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                        <p style="height: 667px; width: 947px">
                            &nbsp;</p>

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
                <td class="style19" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style7">
                </td>
                <td class="style8" style="" bgcolor="#FFFF99">
                    Copyright&nbsp; Imam Mahdi Association of Marjeya</td>
                <td class="style7">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
     <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use any Extender in Content Page, the $find method’s parameter should access the Extender’s BehaviorID.

add the BehaviorID property to the MaskedEditExtender:

```
       <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender6" BehaviorID="MaskedEditExtender6" runat="server" Mask="999" 
            DisplayMoney="None" MaskType="number" TargetControlID="TextBox4" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" 
            InputDirection="RightToLeft" AutoComplete="False"> 
        </ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing Mask Value of MAskEditExtender, One has to use

```
$find('ID of element').set_Mask("new value of mask");
$find('ID of element')._convertMask();
```

or

```
$find('ID of element')._MaskConv = "new value for mask";
```